# is it right way to use interface?

Tags: c#-3.0

how interface knows which class method to call?
it is the correct code? or not

```
namespace IntExample
{
    interface Iinterface
    {
       void add();
       void sub();
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form,Iinterface
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void add()
        {

            int a, b, c;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum2.Text);
            c = a + b;
            txtresult.Text = c.ToString();



        }
        public void sub()
        {

            int a, b, c;
            a = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum1.Text);
            b = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum2.Text);
            c = a - b;
            txtresult.Text = c.ToString();

        }


        private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            add();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sub();
        }



        class cl2 : Form1,Iinterface
        {

            public void add()
            {

                int a, b, c;
                a = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum1.Text);
                b = Convert.ToInt32(txtnum2.Text);
                c = a + b;
                txtresult.Text = c.ToString();



            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Interface does not "know" which class method to call. It just *defines* what methods are available.

The code you posted would not compile since `cl2` does not implement `sub` method but it's pretty much meaningless anyway.

I have no idea what you are trying to do so I will give example for valid usage of the interface.

You can have several forms implementing that interface, then in your main form you can choose which of those forms to show according to index or name.

So, to store all the forms you can use generic list:

```
List<Iinterface> forms = new List<Iinterface>();
```

Adding to the list all the forms implementing the interface:

```
forms.Add(new Form1());
forms.Add(new Form2());
forms.Add(new Form3());
//...
```

Then you can show specific form and call a method from the interface:

```
//find by index:
forms[index].Show();
forms[index].add();

//find by name:
string name="form 2";
Iinterface form = forms.Find(f => f.Name == name);
if (form != null)
{
    form.Show();
    form.add();
}
```

Comment: thaks for answer?can u tell me how to create log file in c#

Comment: This is totally irrelevant to this question, please ask a new one.